# How to display image behind TableView in Xcode

Tags: xcode, image, background

I want to add a background image behind my table view. 
I have my file staticTableControl.m where I populate the table and I have added 
      -(void)viewDidLoad{

```
      self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage      imageNamed:@"disk2.jpg"]];
     [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

at the top, but the image doesn't load - please can someone advise me what else I need to do?
Thank you

There have been some other questions about background images for tables, but I couldn't find one specifically for this.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to change the tableview background color to transparent and add an imageview behind it

Comment: I have tried that, but whenever I drag the image view object onto the screen, it does not allow me to drop it there. When I drag it straight to the list of objects on the table scene, I can place it as a sub category of the table view, in which case the image appears as a small image above the table, or if it is at the same level it just doesn't appear. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'd really appreciate any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong. Thanks