# Xcode - Changing color of the area behind tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, colors, background, tableview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P5hU.png

When you attempt to scroll past the limits of the tableview, there's a gray area behind it - above the search bar here. Is there a way to access it?

I think a question with a slightly similar aim was asked here, to no avail.

[How to display image behind TableView in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633058/how-to-display-image-behind-tableview-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

In the viewDidLoad(), add code similar to:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

Or the alternate, as your tableview if greater than the height of the iPhone screen is to disable 'bounces' in Storyboard tableview controller for the scroll. This will means the 'background' behind the tableview isn't shown.